# how to render a page into the target frameset in jquery?

Tags: jquery, django, frame, jstree

I have two frame in my website. frame A with a navigation bar and another frame B with the main content.

frame A is a directory listing, a jstree object, which could display all the files' name in my computer.

frame B would display the file's content while I click in frame A. at the same times, the folder in frame A would expend while I click the folder. that is, there would be two events while I click in the frame A(if it is a folder, I would expend the folder in the frame A, and only display the folder's path in frame B).

now, I could expend the folder, but the frame B don't display the file's content while I click the file's name in frame A. what I should do if I want to display the file's content in the frame B?

the page in frame B is a django form:

```
class FileForm(forms.Form):
    path = forms.CharField(max_length = 300, label = u"file path", help_text = u"file full path", error_messages = {"required" : ""})
    text = forms.CharField(max_length = 300, widget = forms.Textarea, label = u"file text", help_text = u"file content", error_messages = {"required" : ""})
```

I could generate a html using this form while I click the file's name in frame A:

```
def get_render_conf_text_info(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        tmp_file_text = ""
        tmp_file_path = ""
        ....
        tmp_form = FileForm(initial = {'path' : tmp_file_path, 'text' : tmp_file_text})
        return render_to_response('conf_nav_right2.html', {'form' : tmp_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        tmp_form = FileForm(initial = {'path' : '', 'text' : ''})
        return render_to_response('conf_nav_right2.html', {'form' : tmp_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

the html codes in frame A like(using jstree.js):

```
<ul>
<li id="file_0_a1.cfg" class="0 jstree-close jstree-leaf" value="0" rel="file">
    <ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>
    <a href="#" class="jstree-clicked" target="conf_nav_right">
        <ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>
        a1.cfg
    </a>
</li>
<li id="folder_1_remote" class="1 jstree-close jstree-leaf" value="0" rel="folder">
    <ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>
    <a href="#" class="">
        <ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>
        remote
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

"**conf_nav_right**" is the frame B's name.

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve this problem, just use function write() in htmldocument.

if you meet this problem also, try it.